# In Mintty(terminal people favour for cygwin), can you get ENTER to not send a carriage return when text is highlighted?

Tags: mintty

In Mintty(terminal people favour for cygwin), can you get ENTER to not send a carriage return when text is highlighted?

For example, in cmd, if you go to properties..options..quickedit mode, then you can highlight text and hit ENTER and it copied,  (without sending a 'carriage return, line feed' to the terminal! / without the terminal starting a new line).

I know it is possible to run cygwin from cmd.exe and cygwin used to by default. And can still be run from there. Though mintty tends to be the preferred terminal for cygwin and is the one that cygwin installs with by default nowadays.

In Mintty, you can set it so that right click pastes.. so that's like cmd's quickedit mode, fine. And you can use highlight and ENTER to copy text. But the problem is that it also sends a new line to the terminal.

Is it possible to get Mintty to not do that? So to be more like cmd.exe(in its quick-edit mode) in that regard. If text is highlighted, and ENTER is pushed, just copy to clipboard, don't start a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not, but that doesn't matter, as Mintty is pretty good for copy/paste,

it has a feature where if you select text then it immediately copies to the clipboard.

An answer mentions that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363890/unable-to-copy-paste-in-mingw-shell  "To copy on MINGW, only highlight whatever you want to copy"

So where you wrote

> And you can use highlight and ENTER to copy text

That's the case in cmd. But for Mintty it's copied as soon as you highlighted.